# Unit Testing Angular Observables

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

I am new to testing world and I have just started writing unit tests for an existing Angular 2 code. I have a function `confirmDelete` which returns `Obserable<boolean>` and internally uses `ConfirmationService` of PrimeNG to get user's feedback on a popup.

Definition of the function is given below:

```
confirmDelete(): Observable<boolean> {
    let confirmObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {            
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            header: 'Delete Confirmation',
            message: 'Do you really want to delete this record?',
            accept: () => {
                observer.next(true);
                observer.complete();            
            },
            reject: () => {
                observer.next(false);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });

    });

    return confirmObservable;

}
```

I want to write a unit test for this piece of code. I planned to write a Stub for the `ConfirmationService` but because I am new to unit testing world, I am finding it difficult to set up the things.

My question is what is the correct approach to write a unit test in this particular scenario.

**EDIT:-**

I tried solution proposed by @peeskillet but then I started getting type mismatch error between `ConfirmationService` and `MockConfirmationService`.

Below are the declarations of `ConfirmationService` and `Confirmation` classes found in the PrimeNG library.

```
export interface Confirmation {
    message: string;
    icon?: string;
    header?: string;
    accept?: Function;
    reject?: Function;
    acceptVisible?: boolean;
    rejectVisible?: boolean;
    acceptEvent?: EventEmitter<any>;
    rejectEvent?: EventEmitter<any>;
}
export declare class ConfirmationService {
    private requireConfirmationSource;
    private acceptConfirmationSource;
    requireConfirmation$: Observable<Confirmation>;
    accept: Observable<Confirmation>;
    confirm(confirmation: Confirmation): this;
    onAccept(): void;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably make the mock hold on to the references of the `accept` and `reject` functions. Then in the test you can call them to check that they emit the correct boolean value. Something like

```
class MockConfirmationService {
  accept: Function;
  reject: Function;

  confirm(config: any) {
    this.accept = config.accept;
    this.reject = config.reject;
  }
}
```

Then in your test just call the `accept` to test that `true` is emitted, and call `reject` to test that `false` is emitted.

```
describe('serivce: ModalService', () => {

  let modalService: ModalService;
  let confirmService: MockConfirmationService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    confirmService = new MockConfirmationService();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ModalService,
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useValue: confirmService }
      ]
    });

    modalService = TestBed.get(ModalService);
  });

  it('should return true when accepted', async(() => {
    modalService.confirmDelete().subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toBe(true);
      console.log('accepted test complete');
    });
    confirmService.accept();
  }));

  it('should return false when rejected', async(() => {
    modalService.confirmDelete().subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toBe(false);
      console.log('rejected test complete');
    });
    confirmService.reject();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks@peeskillet. I tried the above solution but I am getting some type mismatch errors. Please see my edited post above.

Comment: I t  should work. I tested it and it works fine. Look at my example exactly. `ModalService` it nothing but a simple class that takes the `ConfirmationService` as a constructor parameter. And the method, I copy and pasted stright from your post

Comment: If you are trying to do the test without using the TestBed (just instantiating the service under test, and passing the mock to it's constructor), then you need to "cast" the mock before trying to pass it. But using the Testbed, we don't need to worry about these things, as type checking is only compile-time

Comment: What I mean by casting is `new ModalService(<ConfirmationService>confirmService)` or `new ModalService(confirmService as ConfirmationService)`

Answer (score 0):

I've built off of peeskillet's answer.  The ***p-confirmDialog*** component calls the subscribe of the service, so I had to added ***requireConfirmationSource***, which I found in the PrimeNg source.  My mock is as follows:

```
//
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//
export class ConfirmationServiceMock {
    public key: string = 'mock1';
    public header: string = 'Delete Confirmation';
    public icon: string = '';
    public message: string = '';
    //  Call Accept to emulate a user accepting
    public accept: Function;
    //  Call Reject to emulate a user rejecting
    public reject: Function;
    private requireConfirmationSource = new Subject<any>();
    requireConfirmation$ = this.requireConfirmationSource.asObservable();
    //
    public confirm(config: any) {
        console.log( 'In confirm service mock...' );
        this.message = config.message;
        this.accept = config.accept;
        this.reject = config.reject;
        console.log( this.message );
        return this;
    }
}
//
```