# 3rd party dependency mock for Angular2 jasmine test are not initiated correctly

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-services

So I want to create a test for an Angular 2.4.1 service which has a dependency on Apollo.
In the service where I use Apollo I placed a console log to see what kind of object it sees, and what the result of the function 'watchQuery()' is. I expect the log to print 'TEST', but instead I get an 'undefined'.

When I log just 'watchQuery', it will show that is a function with no parameters. When I update the parameters in the mock-class, I will see the mocked parameters in the log.

So it looks like the class is not initiated properly or something.

```
describe('Service: ViewGraphService', () => {

  let viewGraphsService: ViewGraphsService;
  let apolloMock: Apollo;

  class ApolloMock {
    public watchQuery () {
      return 'TEST';
    }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ViewGraphsService,
        {
          provide: Apollo,
          useClass: ApolloMock
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([ Apollo ],
    (apollo: Apollo) => {
      viewGraphsService = new ViewGraphsService(apollo);
      apolloMock = apollo;
    }));

  it('should call apollo when a stream is started', () => {
    // do some tests
  });
```

I also tried to use 'useFactory', but it gave me the same result..

```
class ApolloMock {
    public watchQuery (a) {
      return 'TEST';
    }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ViewGraphsService,
        {
          provide: Apollo,
          useFactory: () => {
            return new ApolloMock();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT 1**

tried this from [Angular 2 - Unit Testing Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592637/angular-2-unit-testing-observables)

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    apolloMock = new ApolloMock();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ViewGraphsService,
        { provide: Apollo, useValue: apolloMock }
      ]
    });

    viewGraphsService = TestBed.get(ViewGraphsService);
  });
```

**EDIT 2**

So, passing in a new instance of the ApolloMock-class directly to the service is working, but this does not feels like the way it is intended to work... For the simple reason that my typings are off now. The ApolloMock-class does not meet the Apollo class/interface which is expected by the service.

```
  beforeEach(inject([ Apollo ],
    (apollo: Apollo) => {
      viewGraphsService = new ViewGraphsService(new ApolloMock());
      apolloMock = apollo;
    }));
```

Comment: Shooting in the void here, but could you try to delete the space between your function and its parameters ? `public watchQuery()` instead of `public watchQuery ()`

Comment: Thanks, but no difference :-)

Comment: And if you inject your service in the test instead of using a foreach ?

Comment: Same result. This however does work [see edit2]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its too late to answer.

I used the window instance and wanted to mock that instance in the spec file. So, here's what I did.

Created a class which returns the reference of the window object. Something like

```
export class WindowReference { public getWindowRef() { return this.window; }}
```

Each time I need the window, I called this getWindowRef.
In this above class spec, I expected windowRef.getWindowRef() to be equal to window.

Now, lets suppose I used this getWindowRef() in some class A.

Please note dependency injection is done for **windowRefernce**

```
export class A {
```

`console.log(this.windowRefernce.getWindowRef())`}

Creating a spec of this :

```
provide: WindowRef, useValue: windowReferenceStub
```

and the windowReferenceStub is like :

```
let windowReferenceStub= {
  getWindowRef: {
    methodName: jasmine.createSpy('methodName'),
  }
};
```

And in before Each :

```
windowRefStub = TestBed.get(WindowRef);
```